# Fread does not read correctly a image file

Tags: c, image, http, webserver, fread

I wrote a web server in C and fread reads for me the data from a File, every text file and so one works fine, but the image file does not really work:

```
char *contentType = (char *) calloc(100, sizeof(char));
    char *header = (char *) calloc(50000, sizeof(char));
    char *fullpath = (char *) calloc(100, sizeof(char));
    char *contentBuffer = (char *) calloc(50000, sizeof(char));

    strcat(fullpath, path);
    strcat(fullpath, route);


    for (int i = 0; 11 > i; i++) {
        if (strstr(fullpath, contentTypes[i].ending) != NULL) {

            strcat(contentType, contentTypes[i].header);
            i = sizeof(contentTypes);
        }
    }


    if (!contentType[0]) {
        strcat(fullpath, "/index.html");
    }

    if (access(fullpath, F_OK) == 0) {

        FILE *htmlData = fopen(fullpath, "r");

        int fileSize = fread(contentBuffer, 1, 50000, htmlData);

        sprintf(header,
                "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: %s\r\n\r\n",
                contentType
        );
        for (int i = 0; i < fileSize; i++) {
            strncat(header, &contentBuffer[i], 1);
        }


        free(contentBuffer);
    } else {
        throwWarning("File requested not found");
        strcat(header, "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\r\n\n");
    }
    free(fullpath);

    throwLog(header);

    return header;
}
```

(This code does not completely clean it, it's just a bit messed up from testing)

I tried to display the image with the other web server and the body of both responses look like this: (left one is mine, right one is the correct working one)

https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/887083209806975067/909578602205577316/unknown.png

What's the reason behind it? And why does every other file work?

Comment: 1: you're reading blindly 50000 bytes, what if the image is larger? 1: you're using `strncat` for appending binary data, this doesn't work. Read the chapter dealing with strings in your C text book.

Comment: `strncat(header, &contentBuffer[i], 1);` You are treating the content as string. That will not work with binary data.

Comment: Please open the a PNG file in binary mode, not in the default mode.

Comment: Oh, and the `for` loop with the `strncat` inside is also a most strange approach. I suggest you learn the basics of the C language before trying to write a webserver.

Comment: @kaylum I understand the problem, but how should i handle it else, i mean i have to return the binary file in the HTML response

Comment: Why the magic numbers? `int fileSize = fread(contentBuffer, 1, 50000, htmlData);` There are plenty of image files which are larger. It's not as though the code loops through the file.

Comment: @Jabberwocky as Ive said in the post, this is not clean at all and it will be cleaned when everything works, the image is under 50k bytes for now and the for loop approach is just to be sure that the bytes get byte per byte in the response, pls concentrate on the question, thx u

Comment: @zgast you didn't mention that your image is less than 5000 bytes (a very small image BTW). The second point of by comment dealing with `strncat` deals with your problem.

Comment: You are using `strncat` to copy individual bytes. This won't work at all for binary data, which can contain zeros (string terminator). I suggest `memcpy` and copy it all at once.

Comment: You *don't* "have to return a binary file". Related: [Why don't we send binary around instead of text on http?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1891993/why-dont-we-send-binary-around-instead-of-text-on-http). You can send hex `12` as text `"12"`.

Comment: https://pastbin.net/untitled-350 thats the code rn, @WeatherVane but the http content looks like that

https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/823276075861409812/910477437060644894/unknown.png

And yes i can send it as a string but it has to contain the binary values

Comment: `fopen(fullpath, "r");` You should open binary files in binary mode: `fopen(fullpath, "rb");`

Comment: @Gerhardh thank u, unfortunatly nothing changed :/